# Using proxy in react (vite) to fix the CORS error

Tags: reactjs, vite

I have the below code in react (Vite) to get the Token from registered app on Azure

```
import axios from "axios";
const index = () => {
  console.log("Fetching the API Token");
  const bodyParameters = {
    client_id: "--------------",
    client_secret: "------------------",
    grant_type: "client_credentials",
    scope: "--------------",
  };
  const instance = axios.create({
    headers: {
  
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
  });
  return instance
    .post(
      "/api/token",
      bodyParameters
    )
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      console.log("API Token fetched successfully");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      console.log("Error happened for fetching API Token");
    });
};

export default index;
```

and I have used the proxy in vite.config.tsx as below to fix the CORS error

```
  server: {
  proxy: {
    
    // Using the proxy instance
    '/api': {
      target: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0',
       changeOrigin: true,
      secure: false,
      }
    }}
```

But it doesn't work and I have the below error:
OST http://localhost:portNumber/api/Token 404 (Not Found)

Note: I can get the token in postman and Azure app is registered as SPA and all settings are set correctly.

Comment: The error message doesn't match your code. It says `/api/Token` but your code uses `/api/token`. Please make sure you're copy / pasting as close to the real values as possible.

Comment: This _might_ work in development (doubtful) but it definitely won't once you build and deploy your app. Microsoft has [specific instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#redirect-uris-for-single-page-apps-spas) for using OAuth flows with SPA apps and the way you're attempting is **not it**.

Answer (score 0):

proxy config need add rewrite.
eg:

```
{
  // Using the proxy instance
  '/api': {
      target: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0',
      changeOrigin: true,
      secure: false,
      rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
    }
  }
}
```